# Proc Report Bookmark Titles in ODS PDF

Tags: sas, ods, proc-report

I am looking to make each proc report that is within the ODS PDF have its own designated title on the third level of the PDF bookmarks. How can I achieve this concept? For example, in the image below, I'd like to change the "Table 1" entry to some other text.

[image]

My code is below:

```
ods escapechar '^';
ods pdf file='S:\Restricted\CITER-ER\BHO Phase II\Transition Monitoring\2. Service Utilization\2. Production\SAS codes\Tinkler\PDF Project\SAS REPORTS PDF\PDFS\table2.pdf' style=Custom;

TITLE  "^{style [JUST= C ]Table 2. Names , 2014}";
TITLE2 "^{style [JUST= C ]State}" ;
Title3 "^{style [JUST= C ]Adult (21 to 64)}";
Title4 "^{style [JUST= C ] Analysis}"  ; 
options orientation=landscape nocenter 
topmargin=.25in 
bottommargin=.25in
leftmargin=.25in rightmargin=.25in ;
ods proclabel "IP"; 
PROC REPORT DATA = Table2x
    style(report)={font_size=9pt cellpadding=2pt cellspacing=.15pt}
    style(header)={background=VLIG foreground=black font_size = 9pt FONT_WEIGHT = bold  just=C }
    style(column)={font_size=8pt just=C}
    STYLE(SUMMARY) = {font_weight=bold};
    WHERE BH_Type = 'MH'  ;
    COLUMN (
       (' ' P_type  )
       (' ' P_name )
       ('MH Inpatient Volume'   AID_Type
        UNIQUSERS  N_Episode  Admis_Tot    Disc_Tot  AvgLOS medianLOS  LOS_C   LOS   T_AMT_PAID  
           AvgCostUser      AvgCostEnc ) );
        Define P_Type /      'MMC Program or Coverage Type'  group  order=data      style(column)= { cellwidth=20mm  just=L    }  ; 
        Define P_name /    'Plan Name or Coverage Type'      group  order=data      style(column)= { cellwidth=30mm    just=L        }  ; 
        Define AID_Type/  'Aid Category'                                                        style(column)= { cellwidth=20mm}  ;         
        Define UNIQUSERS  /    'Unique Users'                               FORMAT=COMMA12.0    style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'     cellwidth=20mm}   ;
        Define N_Episode  /    '# of Episodes^{super 1}'                        FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'  cellwidth=20mm}  ;
        Define Admis_Tot    /    'Admissions^{super 2}'                     FORMAT=COMMA12.     style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'   cellwidth=20mm}    Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold}       ;
        Define Disc_Tot   /      'Discharges^{super 2}'                     FORMAT=COMMA12.     style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'   cellwidth=20mm}     Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold}      ;
        Define LOS_C  /    'Hospital Days^{super X}'        Noprint         FORMAT=COMMA12.     style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'    cellwidth=15mm}    Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold} ;
        DEFINE LOS  /   'LOS for discharged^{super 4}'      Noprint         FORMAT=COMMA12.     style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'  cellwidth=20mm}      Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold} ;
        Define T_AMT_PAID    /    'Total Amount Paid,$'                         FORMAT=DOLLAR14. style(column)= { tagattr='format:$###,###,###'    cellwidth=20mm}  Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold} ;
        Define AVGCOSTUSER    /    'Avg Cost Per User, $'                   FORMAT=DOLLAR14. style(column)= { tagattr='format:$###,###,###'    cellwidth=20mm} ;
        Define AvgLOS     /     'Mean LOS for Discharged Episode'           FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'    cellwidth=20mm}    ;
        DEFINE MEDIANLOS  /     'Median LOS for Discharged Episode'          FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'    cellwidth=20mm}   ;
        Define AVGCOSTENC     /    'Avg. Cost Per Episode, $'                   FORMAT=DOLLAR14. style(column)= { tagattr='format:$###,###,###'    cellwidth=20mm} ;


/* compute P_type;*/
/* if P_Type = 'Total'  THEN   call define(_row_,'style','style={background=VLIP   just=R}'); */
/**/
/* end;*/
/* endcomp;*/

compute P_type;
bg + 1;
if mod(bg, 2) = 1 then
call define(_row_, "style", "style={background=white}");
ELSE call define(_row_, "style", "style={background=#d1e9d1}");
IF  P_Type = 'Total'  THEN   call define(_row_,'style','style={background=VLIP   just=R}');
endcomp;

RUN;

/*Need New Title*/

PROC REPORT DATA = Table2x
    STYLE(header) = {background=VLIG foreground=black font_size = 10pt
                    FONT_WEIGHT = bold  just=C}
    STYLE(column) = {font_size = 12pt  just=R}
    STYLE(SUMMARY) = {font_weight=bold};
    WHERE BH_Type = 'SUD'   ; 
    COLUMN (
       (' ' Year_Month )
       ( ' ' P_type  )
       (' '  P_name )
       ('SUD Inpatient Volume'   AID_Type
        UNIQUSERS  N_Episode  Admis_Tot    Disc_Tot  AvgLOS medianLOS  LOS_C   LOS   T_AMT_PAID  
           AvgCostUser      AvgCostEnc ) );
        DEFINE YEAR_MONTH /   'YEAR and Month'                       style(column)= { cellwidth=20mm  just=L    }  ;
        Define P_Type /      'MMC Program or Coverage Type'                 style(column)= { cellwidth=20mm  just=L    }  ; 
        Define P_name /    'Plan Name or Coverage Type'                       style(column)= { cellwidth=50mm    just=L        }  ; 
        Define AID_Type/  'Aid Category'                                             style(column)= { cellwidth=20mm}  ;        
        Define UNIQUSERS  /    'Unique Users'                               FORMAT=COMMA12.0 style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'     cellwidth=20mm}  ;
        Define N_Episode  /    '# of Episodes~{super 1}'                        FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'  cellwidth=20mm}  ;
        Define Admis_Tot    /    'Admissions~{super 2}'                     FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'   cellwidth=20mm}    Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold}       ;
        Define Disc_Tot   /      'Discharges ~{super 2}'                    FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'   cellwidth=20mm}     Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold}      ;
        Define LOS_C  /    'Hospital Days~{super X}'        Noprint         FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'    cellwidth=15mm}    Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold} ;
        DEFINE LOS  /   'LOS for discharged~{super 4}'      Noprint         FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'  cellwidth=20mm}      Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold} ;
        Define T_AMT_PAID    /    'Total Amount Paid,$'                         FORMAT=DOLLAR14. style(column)= { tagattr='format:$###,###,###'    cellwidth=20mm}  Style(header)={FONT_WEIGHT = bold} ;
        Define AVGCOSTUSER    /    'Avg Cost Per User, $'                   FORMAT=DOLLAR14. style(column)= { tagattr='format:$###,###,###'    cellwidth=20mm} ;
        Define AvgLOS     /     'Mean LOS for Discharged Episode'           FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'    cellwidth=20mm}    ;
        DEFINE MEDIANLOS  /     'Median LOS for Discharged Episode'          FORMAT=COMMA12. style(column)= { tagattr='format:###,###,##0'    cellwidth=20mm}   ;
        Define AVGCOSTENC     /    'Avg. Cost Per Episode, $'                   FORMAT=DOLLAR14. style(column)= { tagattr='format:$###,###,###'    cellwidth=20mm} ;


 compute P_type;
 if P_Type = 'Total'  THEN   call define(_row_,'style','style={background=VLIP   just=R}'); 
 endcomp;

RUN;












ods pdf close;
```

Comment: can you give a more concrete example of what you are looking for?  I am not sure from your question.

Comment: You have to post your code. The method varies depending on if you're using BY groups or multiple PROC REPORTS or some other method. It is possible however, using either Title or ODS TEXT statements.

Comment: I have several proc reports I want to have in one ODS PDF output. These reports will have to have different titles and some different wording. Is it easy to push Proc report X and Proc Report Y-Z out in one ODS PDF with different titles?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a title is as simple as putting another title command where you want it.  It can only be changed between proc runs, but in the case above that's not an issue.

If you want to change the bookmark header, you use `ods proclabel`, which also can be updated between runs.

If you want to change the second level bookmark listing, you use the `contents` option in `PROC REPORT`.

If you want to change the third level bookmark listing, you use the `contents` and `page` option on the `define` statement.

```
ods pdf file="c:\temp\test.pdf";
title "First Run";
ods proclabel="Age";
proc report data=sashelp.class contents="Table Grouped by Age";
  columns age height weight;
  define age/group contents='Table Grouped by Age' page;
  define height/analysis mean;
  define weight/analysis mean;
run;

title "Second Run";
ods proclabel="Sex";
proc report data=sashelp.class contents="Table Grouped by Sex";
  columns sex height weight;
  define sex/group contents='Table Grouped by Sex' page;;
  define height/analysis mean;
  define weight/analysis mean;
run;

title;

ods pdf close;
```

Comment: Is there a way to title inside the PDF different names for different Proc reports as well?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  What does that mean?  When I run the code above I have 2 pages, one with one title, one with the other title.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the naming conventions id like to manipulate in ODS PDF for each Proc report as well. thanks.

Comment: You're talking about the "School Membership" vs "The Report Procedure" bit?

Comment: Yes. Id like to change the name of "Table 1" to whatever I deem and also have the second proc report say "Table 2"

Comment: So not the "School Membership" line, but you want to change the "Table 1".  I see.

Comment: No i know how to alter that line its : [ods proclabel "School membership";]

Comment: Okay - got all three in there, you can edit whichever one you want however you want...

Comment: Thanks Joe. I really appreciate your help this morning!